# Cannot read property 'setState' of null on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a reactjs application and having this issue with accessing state inside updateVert function. When I click on "play" button, actionButton get's called and from inside actionButton, updateVert gets called.

Below is my code snippet

```
updateVert() {

        console.log("inside upver")
        if(play) {
            cancelAnimationFrame(this.updateVert);
            return;
        }

       this.setState({xPos: this.state.xPos + 1}, ()=>{
           if(this.state.xPos >= w) {
               // stop animation...
               this.setState({xPos:0, playing:false});
           }
           ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

           // draw new one...
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.strokeStyle = "#19f";
           ctx.lineWidth = 2;
           ctx.moveTo(this.state.xPos, 0);
           ctx.lineTo(this.state.xPos, 200);
           ctx.stroke();

           if(this.state.playing) {
               console.log("yes true")
               requestAnimationFrame(this.updateVert)
           };
       })
        // reset rectangle content to erase previous line...
    }

    actionButton(){
        if(this.state.playing) {
            // pause...
            this.setState({playing:false},()=>{
                console.log(this.state.playing)
            })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({playing:!this.state.playing},()=>{
                console.log(this.state.playing)
                this.updateVert();
            })

        }
    }

  render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="App">
                    <canvas id="DemoCanvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.actionButton.bind(this)}>{this.state.playing ? "Stop":"Play"}</button>
            </div>


    );
  }
```

When I click on button (play/pause), I get the error saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null
updateVert
src/App.js:45
  42 |      return;
  43 |  }
  44 | 
> 45 | this.setState({xPos: this.state.xPos + 1}, ()=>{
  46 |     if(this.state.xPos >= w) {
  47 |         // stop animation...
  48 |         this.setState({xPos:0, playing:false});
```

I have referenced updateVert function correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not getting the correct `this` context. No need to write extra code for binding. You need to change

```
updateVert() { .... }
```

to

```
updateVert = () => {.... }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing to bind the context `this`:

In the `actionButton(){` hook you're calling `this.updateVert()` which has no binding for `this`. Thus bind it inside the constructor:

```
this.updateVert.bind(this)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to bind context specifically in **requestAnimationFrame**

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.updateVert.bind(this))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: requestAnimationFrame, what is that?

Comment: I know that but what is that used for binding? Any reference? It would be new finding for me :)

Comment: My suggestion was that, the function itself wasn't declared using arrow function notation, so when calling inside of requestAnimationFrame it lost its context. As Anshul's answer suggested you could just specify the function as arrow function, or you could bind context in it specifically

Comment: I'm curious to know how requestAnimationFrame is used for binding the context. FYI, I din't downvote.

Comment: FYI, I din't downvote. - lol, I don't care :). As I said, it was just my suggestion, need to check it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/rwm2lyxlm Here I've created sandbox, which proves, that my answer is right. For proveness, you can bind this to update function in setTimeout: setTimeout(this.update.bind(this), 1000); FIY, it really doesnt matter, if it setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame - the principle stays the same. Hope I've satisfied your curiosity :D

Comment: I agree somehow. But where did you find using requestAnimationFrame for binding the context?